# MongoDB Cannot refer to field with a space

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I have such a document in the collection that contains such a numberId "2 735 908" and it is separated by an unprintable space as I understand it.
when asked to find this number, nothing is displayed, although the document contains it. How to ignore spaces between these numbers in a request?

db.getCollection('doc').find({'data.offers.numberId':'2\u00a0735\u00a0908'})
it doesn't work like that

Comment: You need to properly escape the special characters so that they are passed correctly to the driver. robo3t is not the ideal tool for testing this, try mongo shell or your favorite driver.

Comment: i also use mongo compass same situation

Comment: That is expected.